# Show a Dialog box if the document is Approved or Rejected

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica, if the document is going for multiple approvals, If the approver is not the last approver then its difficult for the user to know whether the document is approved unless they go to the approval tab and check the entry belonging to the user.

So can we customize in a way that it shows an interactive information.
I tried the below and it seems working.

*But in the dialog box if they use the close button, then the doc status is not changing to approved as the call is not coming back and the function is not returning the true/false value*.

Used below class

```
public class MYECApporval<SourceAssign> : PX.Objects.EP.ExpenseClaimEntry.ExpenceClaimApproval<SourceAssign>
                                                where SourceAssign : EPExpenseClaim
{

 public MYECApporval(PXGraph graph)
            : base(graph)
        {
        }

   public override bool Reject(SourceAssign source)
        {
            if (base._Graph.Views[base._Graph.PrimaryView].Answer != WebDialogResult.OK)
            {
                bool retVal = base.Reject(source);

                if (retVal)
                    base._Graph.Views[base._Graph.PrimaryView].Ask("Document Rejected.", MessageButtons.OK);
                return retVal;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And in the Expense claim extension

```
public MYECApporval<EPExpenseClaim> Approval;
```

Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't Document.Ask a type of system exception?  Not sure if the remaining code block is executed after Document.Ask

Comment: Yes, if they click 'ok' button on the message pop-up, the remaining code will be executed. But if the user simply closes it, then it wont execute and totally problem.